# How can I identify chlorophyll and submerged aquatic plants in Google Earth Engine over a small pond?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

```
var collection = ee.FeatureCollection([Sat_samp2]);
Export.table.toDrive({
      collection:collection , 
      description:'lake' , 
      folder:'ROI' , 
      fileFormat:"SHP"})

Map.addLayer(ROI)
Map.centerObject(ROI,16)


var IMG = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
              .filterBounds(ROI)
              .filterDate('2023-08-01', '2023-08-31')
              .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', true)
              .first()
              .clip(ROI)



var nir = IMG.select('B8');  // Near Infrared band
var blue = IMG.select('B2'); // blue band

var ndavi = blue.subtract(nir).divide(blue.add(nir));


var ndaviParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(ndavi, ndaviParams, 'NDAVI');


var nir = IMG.select('B5');  // Near Infrared band
var redEdge = IMG.select('B4'); // Red-edge band

var ndci = nir.subtract(redEdge).divide(nir.add(redEdge));

var ndciParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(ndci, ndciParams, 'NDCI');
```

With this lat long ( 22.578578°,  88.284268°), I created a polygon in Google Earth Engine.
I'm looking for submerged aquatic vegetation and chlorophyll in a recognised pond to see if the code is running properly. However, it appears that it does not reflect my field data, which shows low chlorophyll and little submerged plants. I'm not sure where I went wrong in the codes shown above.